# java ArrayList and LinkedList add

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

Hi i have problem with add Element on index in ArrayList and LinkedList. I dont know how to done it.

I have this ArrayList class and i must do add element on index and i dont know how.(this ->public void add(Object element, int index) in both arrayList and linkedList)

```
public class ArrayList implements List {

    private Object[] elements = new Object[0];

    @Override
    public void add(Object element) {
        Object[] newElements = new Object[elements.length + 1];
        copyArrayElements(elements, 0, newElements, 0, elements.length);
        newElements[newElements.length - 1] = element;
        elements = newElements;
        // výkonově by nemuselo být ideální
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object element, int index) {

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= elements.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Object[] newElements = new Object[elements.length - 1];
        copyArrayElements(elements, 0, newElements, 0, index);
        copyArrayElements(elements, index + 1, newElements, index, elements.length - index - 1);
        elements = newElements;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= elements.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return elements[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return elements.length;
    }

    private void copyArrayElements(Object[] src, int srcPos, Object[] dest, int destPos, int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            dest[destPos + i] = src[srcPos + i];
        }
    } // System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length);

}
```

and similar problem on LinkedList.

```
public class LinkedList implements List {

    private Node first;
    private int size; // aby se velikost nemusela vždy dopočítávat, tj. procházet celý seznam

    @Override
    public void add(Object element) {
        if (first == null) {
            first = new Node(element, null);
        } else {
            Node node = first;
            while (node.next != null) {
                node = node.next;
            }
            node.next = new Node(element, null);
        }
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object element, int index) {

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        if (index == 0) {
            first = first.next;
        } else {
            Node node = first;
            for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
                node = node.next;
            }
            node.next = node.next.next;
        }
        size--;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node node = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            node = node.next;
        }
        return node.item;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    private class Node {

        private Object item;
        private Node next;

        Node(Object item, Node next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = next;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: For an ArrayList, move all the elements at and after the add point over by one, starting at the end and working your way back to the add point.  Then insert the element at the add point.  For a LinkedList, break the links at the add point, add the element, and reestablish the links between the element at index - 1, index, and index + 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert elements to ArrayList to the index position or directly at the end of the list.

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // Insert at the end of the list
        list.add("Apple");
        list.add("Banana");
        //Items in List: [Apple, Banana]

        // Index based insert
        list.add(0,"Orange");
        list.add(1,"Mango");
        //Items in List: [Orange, Mango, Apple, Banana]

        System.out.println(list);

    }

}
```

Similar way applies to Linked List as well.

Java Doc Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Yes, but i must write the method in depth, like other methods in these clases, and thats what i cant do.